# Is it correct to state that this is 2/3 time signature?

Tags: time-signatures

Basically, if this is 4/4 (i.e. 4 beats aka 1 bar, 4 clocks):

[image]

and this is 1/4 (i.e. 1 beat aka 1/4 bar, 4 clocks):

[image]

is it correct to state that this is 2/3? (i.e. 2 beats aka half bar, 3 clocks):

[image]

Comment: The short answer is "no." It seems that there's some confusion about the difference between time signature and rhythms. These examples have notes of different lengths (durations), but they could be part of many different time signatures. There's no such thing, though, as "2/3" (at least, not normally). Try reading up, here and elsewhere, about terms like "meter," "note value," and "rhythm." And you might call example 3 "hemiola," though I wouldn't worry about that before understanding the others.

Comment: Your question demonstrates that you do not understand how time signatures work.  I kindly suggest that you do some googling and read up on the subject.  Wikipedia is a free and convenient place to start.  If you still have questions after reading the relevant theory, then come back and ask a new question.  Notice that you will only ever see powers of 2 on the bottom of a time signature.  Anything else is invalid, a clue that you have misunderstood what is going on.

Comment: In conventional notation, the time signature tells you how many beats of what duration make up a full bar.  Your 1/4 example is incorrect because in a 1/4 time signature, one beat is one bar, not a quarter of a bar.

Answer (score 2):

No.

What you have shown isn't a bar with an unusual length anyway.   It's a standard 4-beat bar partially filled by three triplet quarter-notes.

Time signatures work like this.   The top number is 'how many' the bottom number is 'what of'.   And the 'what of' is worked out by 'how many would add up to a whole note'.  (Just like fractions in math, really.)

The most common bottom number is 4.  Four quarter notes add up to a whole note. (That's why they're called 'quarter notes'.)

The most common top number is also 4.   How many quarter notes in each bar?  Four.  A standard rock beat has that. A waltz has 3, so the time signature would be 3/4.

You COULD, theoretically, make the 'what of' a third of a whole note.  But we don't, the convention is to use only 'what of' numbers divisible by 2.

(There is a modern-ish thing of 'irrational time signatures' where a signature such as 2/3 is used to indicate a tempo relationship with what came before.   And the top number 'how many' doesn't always directly count the beat.  But let's not get complicated.)

Answer (score 1):

3/4 means you have three beats of length 1/4 each measure. What you’ve given us would be rather a 6/8 (two groups of 3 subbeats per measure). But the way your program is handling this currently is to divide the space of a 1/2 note into three spaces, so you get two quarter note triplets. This is rhythmically the same as 6/8, but instead of 1/8 it uses two thirds of 1/4 as base unit (so for same output one has to increase the tempo 50%).

Your software should provide the option to select the time signature somewhere. So if you change the sig to 3/4 you should see in the top the "2" one block earlier.

Comment: Not really a 6/8 so, since its not 6 beats with length 1/8 measure, but 3 beats of 1/6 measure. So maybe 3/6? Make sense? Also, I don't need to have "2" one block earlier anyway :)

Comment: @markzzz The grid in the background is what relates visually to the notion of "time signature." The notes shown here divide 8 cells into three—they're derived from triplets. But music is notated in certain conventions; there's no such thing as a "sixth note." Even "compound meter," in which notes fall in groups of three—like 6/8—calls these notes "eighth notes" even though there are 6 of them in a measure.

Comment: @markzzz One of the important distinctions is: These are "notes," but they aren't necessarily "beats." "Notes" are "real"—you can hear differences in length—but "beats" are "imaginary"; they're an idea we use to organize the real sounds in time. And "meter" is another construct formed by adding up the imaginary "beats."

Comment: @markzzz The notes would fit into a 6/6 measure, if you so want. But what the grid in your software is suggesting is still 4/4 (note that the notes do *not* align to the grid).

Comment: @Lazy well, 6/6 if I fill all of them :) If I use 3/6, its like "filling" just 3 instead of 6 in the score. Similarly: 3/4 is like sequence 3 beats instead of 4. In any case, the length of the beats (3 vs 6, or 3 vs 4) shouldn't change. Does it make some sense?

Comment: I'm basically modelling a software that need to fill divisions :) So probably the terminology is wrong. In fact 6/6 duration will be longer than 4/4 given the same tempo/bpm... but in my case it just need to divide properly in the same time unit. Not sure how to describe that division, keeping the reference to a beat.

Comment: @markzzz Commonly bpm is used for quarters, so 4/4 and 6/6 are of same length given the same bpm. More classically we’d give a metronome number, which might refer to different beats. Anyway, I thing it should make sense to continue this discussion in chat if required.

Comment: @Lazy anyway, thats basically a 1/4T :)

Comment: @markzzz the bottom number in a time signature doesn't tell you what fraction of a measure each beat represents.  The top number tells you that.

Comment: @markzzz furthermore, given that the time signature tells you how many beats are in a measure, it should be obvious that 6/8 cannot mean 6 beats that each take up 1/8 of a measure, because if that were true then you would be saying that each measure is 0.75 measures long, which is nonsense.  (This is actually somewhat closer to what time signatures meant when they were first introduced, but measures hadn't quite been invented yet and the time signature was a true fraction, unlike its use today.  But getting into that in too much detail is probably more confusing than helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

The math is right, but the music theory is wrong because the underlying time signature can't have a 3 as its beat value. Since the only context available is that your DAW seems to be subdividing as though it's 4/4, this is a triplet rhythm in 4/4, which isn't unusual in many styles of music. Specifically, this is a quarter note triplet.

This rhythm could easily be expressed in another time signature, for example something like 3/4 or 6/8 would this rhythm simpler since those time signatures are based around rhythmic patterns of threes. Whether or not that is appropriate depends heavily on the rest of the music, though.

Outside of experimental notation, there is no such thing as 2/3 time signature. This is because the beat value (bottom number) of a time signature represents a note value, usually the note value on which the beat falls. In 4/4, the bottom 4 represents a quarter note, or 1/4 of a whole note. The bottom note will always be a power of two in accordance with the value of notes.

The extreme example is irrational time signatures, where the 2/3 would mean something like the three represents a hypothetical note that takes up 1/3 of a whole note (duration of one of the three notes in a half-note triplet). The idea is this would be used to show that the new beat has some mathematical relationship to the previous tempo. Therefore, this notation is only used as an experimental way to describe metric modulations rather than a real time signature in the traditional sense. *I would not advise using this in your sheet music unless you know that the reader of your music really really knows what they're doing.*

Comment: Curious thing: why bottom need to be power of 2? If I can divide by 4 (or 8), why can't divide it also by 3?

Comment: Maybe because by convention, a quarter note is a beat? So it must divide/multiply from this?

Comment: In fact, on a DAW, i can basically set 1/3 of beat, which would be 1/12 note. Are you saying 1/12 note doesn't exist?

Comment: @markzzz Correct, it's called a "triplet." Perhaps part of the problem is that you've come to a site about conventional music notation and practice, and want to propose some non-traditional practices. You can do whatever you want, you just can't expect others to understand you unless you use the language that's been established.

Comment: @markzzz I mean, *in music you can have a note of any duration* including 1/12 of a whole note. The reason time signatures don't let you use 12 as the denominator is because time signatures come from *sheet music*, and sheet music is written in such a way that durations are expressed as powers of 2, hence why in sheet music we don't have a "one-twelfth note". Sheet music allows for notes to be 1/12th of a whole note, but it requires tuplet notation. Hence we would say that's an "eighth note triplet".

Comment: @markzzz the bottom number is always a power of two because the duration of each kind of note is twice as long as the next shorter note and half as long as the next longer note.  The factor is always 2.  There is an exception for tuplets, most commonly triplets, but these are written using the standard power-of-two notes and adding a number above them to indicate how much faster they are to be played; the time signature is never used for that because there is no way of drawing a note that (by itself) represents anything other than a power of two; you have to use the tuplet annotation.

Comment: @AndyBonner "you just can't expect others to understand you unless you use the language that's been established": it would be possible to have people understand a novel nontraditional practice if there is a thorough specification describing the practice.  The real problem is convincing people to use it.

Comment: And what if I want (for example) play a beat using 7 division? How can be noted this if 1/28 is not allowed and since this is not a triplet?

Comment: @markzzz There is a thing in conventional sheet music called a septuplet, notated as 7 eighth notes  in the time of 8. Other values are allowed as well.

Comment: @Jos so I can have both Quarter Septuplet or Eighth Septuplet?

Comment: Yes, and if that isn't complicated enough, you can have e.g. 7 septuplets in the time of three regular eights, notated as 7:3 above the notes.